# R - Calculate percentage of occurrences in data.table by month

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with multiple soil measurements per day. Soil moisture ranges from 0-0.8 and there are some NA's as well:

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                                    length.out = 365, by = "1 day"), 5e1, replace = TRUE), 
                  sm = sample(c(NA, runif(10, min=0, max=0.8)), 5e1, replace = TRUE))
```

I am trying to calculate, by each month, the following statistics:

1. percentage of NA's;
2. percentage of soil moisture values within classes (e.g. `0 to 0.2`, `0.2 to 0.4`, `0.4 to 0.6` and `0.6 to 0.8`).

In the provided example `df1`, there are five measurements for january. One out of five is NA, hence NA should total 20%. There is also `0.13`, which would fit the `0-0.2` class. Hence, 20%. There are two `0.23` values, which is in the `0.2-0.4` class, hence 50%. The final `0.68` value goes to the `0.6-0.8` class, which is 20% of the total for january.

This is the expected result:

```
month   NA   0-0.2   0.2-0.4   0.4-0.6   0.6-0.8
1       20%    20%     40%        0%       20%
2        0%    0%      50%       25%       25%
3        0%    0%    16.6%     16.6%       66.8%
...
```

My unsuccessful attempt to calculate `1.` was the following:

```
DT[, .(percentage = 100 * sum(is.na(.SD))/length(.SD)), by=month(DT$date)]
```

but it yields some non-sense percentage values.

Any ideas on how to get there? Thanks!

Comment: why is the percentage of `na` for april 1.2%?

Comment: when you say "by each month", is it just the month, regardless of year, or for each year, each month? Also, in your expected output, shouldn't all the columns add up to a 100 % since we are talking about the contribution of each towards the set?

Comment: It is better to show a reproducible example and the expected output on that example.  The current example creates confusion on those who wanted to help you.  I

Comment: Could you create a dummy dataset?  Are these percentages, the percentage of NA elements.  I am not completely sure

Comment: The answer is: just some fake data, in order to illustrate the expected output...

Comment: Are you saying that there are 17% NA values for month 1 in the group 0 - 0.2.  I also see an NA as column name.

Comment: No, I was saying that for January (month 1) there are 1.7% of NA values, 17% of `0-0.2`, 15% of `0.2-0.4`, 14% of `0.4-0.6`, and 13% of `0.6-0.8`. The proportions are not real, they are just to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `tidyverse`.  Convert the 'date' to `Date` class (if not already), extract the `month` from 'date', create a grouping variable with `cut` based on the 'sm' column, grouped by 'month' and 'grp' get the number of elements of each group (`n()`) and divide by the total number of rows for each month and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(month = month(date)) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cut(sm, breaks = seq(0, 0.8, by = 0.2)), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(perc = 100 * n()/first(n)) %>% 
  spread(grp, perc, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups: month [12]
#   month `(0,0.2]` `(0.2,0.4]` `(0.4,0.6]` `(0.6,0.8]` `<NA>`
# * <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1.00      20.0        40.0         0          20.0   20.0
# 2  2.00       0          50.0        25.0        25.0    0  
# 3  3.00       0          16.7        16.7        66.7    0  
# 4  4.00      14.3        42.9        42.9         0      0  
# 5  5.00      33.3        16.7         0          50.0    0  
# 6  6.00       0         100           0           0      0  
# 7  7.00       0          66.7         0           0     33.3
# 8  8.00      20.0        60.0        20.0         0      0  
# 9  9.00      14.3        28.6        28.6        14.3   14.3
#10 10.0       50.0        50.0         0           0      0  
#11 11.0        0         100           0           0      0  
#12 12.0        0          33.3        66.7         0      0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df1)[,  n := .N, month(ymd(date))][, .(perc = 100 * .N/n[1]),  
  by = .(month = month(ymd(date)),
   grp = cut(sm, breaks = seq(0, 0.8, by = 0.2),
    labels = c('0 - 0.2', '0.2 - 0.4', '0.4 - 0.6', '0.6 - 0.8')))] 

dcast(tmp, month ~ grp, value.var = 'perc')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
  length.out = 365, by = "1 day"), 3e4, replace = TRUE), 
   sm = sample(c(NA, rnorm(10)), 3e4, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: @thiagoveloso  I added a dummy example.  Could you confirm if this is the output you expect

Comment: @thiagoveloso  added data.table method.  But, I think the `cut` would be the limiting step

Comment: it doesn't work... The percentages on each row (month) must add up to 100%. Please see the update expected example.

Comment: It looks like there is a "do it by month" missing in your code, but I'm not sure where

Comment: @thiagoveloso  It is grouped by month and the cut group.  If you can provide a reproducible example it would be great

Comment: I provided a reproducible example now. Please check the original post.

Comment: @thiagoveloso  Can you now check the update.  I think it was the division created the problem

Comment: Both versions work! Thank you very much for your help @akrun

Comment: I found a situation where this code produces an unexpected result

Comment: @thiagoveloso  It is better to explain where it occurs and a small reproducible example of that situation with expected output

Comment: please consider the data frame I am generating in the original post. It creates values ranging from 0 to 0.8 right? Likewise, your answer classifies values in that same range (`cut(sm, breaks = seq(0, 0.8, by = 0.2)`). However, let's add one more break to your answer, say `cut(sm, breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2)`. The generated output just "ignores" this category, since there is no data falling inside it. Is there any way to preserve the category, assigning either 0 or NA to it?

Comment: @thiagoveloso  It is outside the category you have in the data.  Then you may need to specify it in `labels` to assign it to the value of choice

Comment: it does not work even adjusting the labels accordingly. I suspect it is the `cut` function that omits values outside of breaks

Comment: The labels and breaks length should match.  You are creating a label where it is outside the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165307/discussion-between-thiagoveloso-and-akrun).

Comment: @thiagoveloso  It is not clear to me.  I tried this `cut(2:6, breaks = seq(2, 12, by = 2), right = FALSE, labels = c('2-4', '4-6', '6-8', '8-10', '10-12'))#[1] 2-4 2-4 4-6 4-6 6-8`

Comment: it works like this, but please count the occurrences in each category. it will ignore categories `8-10`and `10-12`, since the vector goes only from 2 to 6.

Comment: I think that this problem can be fixed by using `table`, which keeps all categories defined by breaks, even if they are outside the data range. I wonder if there is any way to count NA's in data table using `table`, rather than the approach you use in the accepted answer?

Comment: I have started a new question. If you have the chance, please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836376/r-overcome-cut-ignoring-values-outside-of-range-in-data-table

Comment: @thiagoveloso  There is a `useNA` argument in `table`  which can take `"always"` as value