# R - overcome "cut" ignoring values outside of range in data table

Tags: r, data.table, categories, binning

I am comparing two years worth of daily soil moisture (SM) measurements. In one year, SM ranged from 0 to 0.6.
In the other year, which had more rain, SM ranged from 0 to 0.8. Amongst the data, I also have some `NA's`, where the SM sensor did not work for some reason.
Let's re-create something similar:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(24)
dt1 <- data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out=365, by="1 day"), 
                  sm=sample(c(NA, runif(10, min=0, max=0.6)), 365, replace = TRUE))

dt2 <- data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out=365, by="1 day"), 
                  sm=sample(c(NA, runif(10, min=0, max=0.8)), 365, replace = TRUE))
```

I am trying to compare both datasets based on the proportion of values between classes of SM in each month.
The classes I am interested in are `seq(0, 0.8, by=0.2)`. I also need to count the proportion of failed measurements (`NA`) per month.

I managed to do that by using `akrun`'s helpful answer here:
[R - Calculate percentage of occurrences in data.table by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657034/r-calculate-percentage-of-occurrences-in-data-table-by-month)

```
tmp1 <- dt1[, n := .N, month(date)][, .(perc=100 * .N/n[1]),
                                    by=.(month=month(date),
                                         grp=cut(sm, breaks=seq(0, 0.8, by=0.2),
                                                 labels = c('0-0.2', '0.2-0.4', '0.4-0.6', '0.6-0.8')))]

tmp2 <- dt2[, n := .N, month(date)][, .(perc=100 * .N/n[1]),
                                    by=.(month=month(date),
                                         grp=cut(sm, breaks=seq(0, 0.8, by=0.2),
                                                 labels = c('0-0.2', '0.2-0.4', '0.4-0.6', '0.6-0.8')))]
```

However, the output is not exactly what I expect. **Since values in `dt1` range only from 0 to 0.6, there is no `0.6-0.8` category at all in the resulting data table `tmp1`.**

It looks like `cut` ignores the last category (`0.6-0.8`) because there is no SM measurement within that range. This makes my comparison really inconvenient, because I don't have the same groups in the resulting data tables `tmp1` and `tmp2`.

Does anybody know how to fix this, i.e. how to "force" `cut` to consider values outside the break range? I need all SM categories in both `tmp1` and `tmp2`, even if their count is 0.

Just as a reference, this issue does not happen if we use `table`, which always shows all categories even if their count is zero:

```
t1 <- runif(10, 0, 0.6)
t2 <- runif(10, 0, 0.8)

table(cut(t1, breaks=seq(0, 0.8, by=0.2)))

  (0,0.2] (0.2,0.4] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.8] 
        5         3         2         0 
table(cut(t2, breaks=seq(0, 0.8, by=0.2)))

  (0,0.2] (0.2,0.4] (0.4,0.6] (0.6,0.8] 
        1         3         2         4
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: `cut` has arguments like `right` and `include.lowest` that i believe solve your problem

Comment: @MichaelChirico No, unfortunately those arguments don't address `cut` ignoring "empty" bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CJ` to count all levels, even those that don't appear in the table:

```
f = function(d){

    # create month column
    d[, month := month(date)]

    # roll to make cut-group column
    mdt = data.table(sm = c(NA, seq(0, .8, by=.2)))
    d[, lb := mdt[.SD, on=.(sm), roll=TRUE, x.sm]]

    # join with CJ to ensure all levels are present
    res = d[CJ(month = month, lb = mdt$sm, unique = TRUE), on=.(month, lb), .N, by=.EACHI]

    # rescale to monthly pct
    res[, pct := N/sum(N), by=month][]

}

# try it
f(dt1)
f(dt2)
```

You could also do this with `cut`. The important thing is how you're tabulating results, not how you're grouping them...

Comment: Fwiw, I wrote up another example of using CJ to fill in levels http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#self-join-to-fill-in-missing-levels

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am still validating it on my real dataset but it seems to work fine. Is there any way to account for the proportion of `NA` values as well? I am still trying to fully digest this code...

Comment: @thiagoveloso Oh, I forgot to include those, but I think my edit fixed it.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Since we are not using `cut`, I have one question though. How are the 'boundaries' accounted for in this method? For example, a value of `0.2` would be classified within `0-0.2` or `0.2-0.4`?

Comment: @thiagoveloso The intervals are like [0.0, 0.2), [0.2, 0.4), .... [0.8, Inf), with anything below 0.0 being assigned NA. It works out this way because we `roll` to the nearest value below. See `?data.table` for how to instead roll to the nearest value above (... I think it's `roll = -Inf`).